# SQL Virtual Box and VMwarestation

Tags: mysql, sql

When i type in the command: `Select * from user;` I get this:[image]

So i can't really read anything in it? How come this happens? It happens in both Virtual Box and VMwarestation.

Comment: Please kindly try to give a more meaningful title to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the normal output, and you will get this whatever the environment. The output is wider than your console, and each line of the output spans on multiple lines on your terminal.

Suggestions:

1. Try selecting less columns: `SELECT user, name FROM mysql.user`
2. Try the (case-sensitive) `\G` terminator (instead of `;`).
3. Send this to a text file and read it in your favourite text editor:

```
    mysql> SELECT * FROM user INTO OUTFILE 'output.txt';
```

or

```
    bash> mysql [options] -e"SELECT * FROM user;" > output.txt
```

Comment: Where is output.txt located?

Comment: `INTO OUTFILE` sends the file into the MySQL data directory (`/var/lib/mysql` by default on most Linux boxes). You can also specify an absolute path where the mysql server has sufficient access.

Comment: Why can't i scroll in virtual box or vmware

Comment: You can: SHIFT+PageUp/PageDown

Comment: @loko - Why blame VirtualBox and VMWare? The whole idea of virtualizacion is that you run a host OS as if it was a physical computer. The font in your screenshot suggests you are using a Windows command line prompt. Right click on the title bar, go to "Properties" and adjust the screen buffer to your liking.

Comment: @yak i dont understand how the password is so random.

Comment: @loko, is your problem related to 1. Formatting the output of your queries 2. Scrolling your terminal or 3. The actual data contained in `mysql.user` ?

Comment: @yak actually all of them now.

Comment: @loko Then please kindly create a question for each of these unrelated issues (I am aware that, from your point of view, they are related, but this is purely concidental). Please also find a better title for your question.

Comment: @yak Okay i will but this quetion is about formatting the output.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this post: http://leefrancis.org/2008/03/07/the-alternative-way-to-select-readable-data-from-mysql/

```
SELECT * FROM table \G
```

If you execute this command

```
\P less;
```

before

```
SELECT * FROM users \G;
```

you can scroll through the output and actually read the values if your console lacks a buffer.

Comment: I get a big ass row but i can't scroll up.

Comment: I don't belive that. Try `SELECT * FROM users \G;` not `SELECT * FROM users; \G` This will format your query in a vertical format (one col per row)

Comment: @loko - The [\G command](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/mysql-commands.html) has been around since MySQL 3. How comes it doesn't work?

Comment: @loko - Then don't confuse everyone saying it doesn't work. You want to display like 8000 columns of text in a 80x25 window. What do you want it to look like?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario it didn't work at first but i didn't do a capital G

Comment: So what do you expect? a proper output with rows and columns and a neat scrollbar that you can drag with your mouse? Maybe some editing functionality? Then use a mysql client gui (Workbench or phpmyadmin). Once in a while I need the mysql console client on a server that is only accessible via SSH and in that case it fits it's needs. For everything else, you can use other tools.